# how Cassandra read one column in one partition fast?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0

create table (id int primary key, c1 int, c2 int, ....c1000 int);

i know that RDBMS stores all columns of such one row continuously.if i want to query c400 of only one row, i can locate the row fast, but have to read out the whole file and then find the c400 value, thus when i want to query all the c400 values of the table, that means all the columns and all the rows will be read.

if i create the same table in cassandra and specify the column "id" as partition key.i know c1,c2,...c1000 in one partition will be stored like below :

{c1:1, c2:123, c3:45, ....., c1000: 10}

that's k-v store structure but is still columns continously stored.when i want to read column c400 of one partition, how cassandra fast read it without scaning the other columns?

Answer (score 0):

It scans the columns, thats why it is recommende to avoid wide rows. Wider your rows are slower is your reads. Also wide rows put more pressure on heap.